# distinct method not working correctly in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to get distinct pair of quarter and year but following query is giving duplicate pairs

```
DataValue.objects.values('period_quarter','period_year').distinct()
```

output:

```
[
 {
'period_year': '2019',
'period_quarter': 'Q2'
 },
 {
'period_year': '2019',
'period_quarter': 'Q2'
 },
 {
'period_year': '2019',
'period_quarter': 'Q2'
 }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [**Docs**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct):

> When you specify field names, you must provide an order_by() in the
>   QuerySet, and the fields in order_by() must start with the fields in
>   distinct(), in the same order.

Try:

```
DataValue.objects.order_by('period_quarter','period_year').distinct('period_quarter','period_year')
```